# Error while installing powerline

Tags: bash, plugins, console, virtual-console, powerline-plugin

I recently installed powerline for bash and it seems to work fine but it made my terminal to load very slow. But when my main concern is when i go to my console pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> it shows some error like shown in the figure. How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Additional information needed. Which version of  ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Got the same issue on 18.04, seems there is no bash integration in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the deb package changed the shell integration scripts.

They are located in `/usr/share/powerline/bindings/`.

Add this to your .bashrc in your home directory:

```
# Powerline
powerline-daemon -q
POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
source /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```